# How to add abilities to the JW Player (and customize it)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, json, jwplayer

I want to create a custom video player.

I already have implemented the default player to play my streamed movies from Amazon S3 and my goal is to :

- customize completely the skin of the player
- add new abilities to the player like add text, images, drawings on the video at some cue points.
- make the player interact with javascript and forms using json for encapsulate the data

For exemple (in an admin section) :

- A "creator" want to add some text and a drawing on a movie (duration 4:00)
- He seek 1:30 and add a red bold text label: "Watch this carefully !"
- He seek 2:05 and add a white rectangle with 50% of opacity to overlay something
- etc...
- The player send json data to javascript
- The "creator" submit the form and json-data are inserted in the database

In the frontend, some user play the video and see the text at 1:30 and the drawing at 2:05.

What is the best way to customize the player in this case: Create a plugin ? Create a new player extending the JW Player ?
By the way, I a AS2 / AS3 programmer and I don't know Flex.

Thank you very much for your answers !

Fro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after lots of experiments I've found a nice way to extend the player.
I've choose to modify and build the JW Player's fl5 project with Flash builder.

More informations:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/addons/using-plugins/18330/help-for-adding-functionalities-to-the-player